# Conditionally skip compilation of C# source files

Tags: c#, build, compilation

I need to include certain source files only if my project is in certain bulid configurations. Is this possible?

I've currently duplicated `Debug` and `Release` and created `DebugAlt` and `ReleaseAlt`. I need to compile certain forms only in Debug and Release, and exclude them in the alternate configs.

Can I write something like this into the `.csproj` file?

```
 <Compile Include="frmTools.cs" Condition="CONFIG=Debug OR Config=Release"/>
```

**Update:**

According to the [MS Build docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164307.aspx) this is supposed to be possible with something like this:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Include="frmTools.cs">
              <SubType>Form</SubType>
            </Compile>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

This works halfways; The project loads perfectly but `frmTools` NEVER compiles. Its because the When condition always evaluates to false. Why? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the point of this?  You don't pay for code that your program doesn't use.

Comment: Hans, the point of this (for me) is to be able to keep debug classes and forms in a project that can't be in the release version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164307.aspx therefore.

Please consider that you need to edit the project file manually in a text editor, Visual Studio does not allow you to edit this via GUI.

However, you can still open the projects in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working with this. Looking up the `DefineConstants` array allows you to check if a certain constant var has been defined, and include/exclude source files accordingly.

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('MYCONST'))">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Include="frmTools.cs">
              <SubType>Form</SubType>
            </Compile>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

Instead of checking which project config is active, we simply add a const to a few project configs and then check the const value in the Project XML.

Comment: Thanks, Robinicks.  I modified your answer slightly so I have ... 
    <Compile Include="DebugForm.cs" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('DEBUG_FORMS'))">